# How to prevent Windows Server 2008 R2 from automatically shutting down applications?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, remote-desktop, troubleshooting

I have been running various processes over night on a Windows 2008 R2 AMD64 SP1 virtual server share via a VPN connection and remote desktop.  Recently, I have been noticing that when I return in the morning, the processes I had started the previous night are stopped and the applications have been shut down (I am the only one who uses this share).  Sometimes the processing completes as expected and other times cuts out mid way--likely after the application encounters an error and is idle.  I am primarily using ArcGIS 10.2 and Python geoprocessing scripts via IDLE or PythonWin.

I have tried investigating the Session Time Limits within the Local Group Policy Editor without success (see attached screenshot).  I was following the instructions from this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2007/09/28/terminal-services-remoteapp-session-termination-logic.aspx).  It appears that all of the settings are at the default, which should not impose a timelimit on applications.  Is there a way to ensure programs are not automatically shut down (even after an error occurs), or at least find a way to track why a program or operation was shut down?

[image]

Comment: In your screenshot, you highlighted a setting that pertains to RemoteApp. But I'm not clear as to whether you're actually running applications over RemoteApp, or logging into the server interactively via Remote Desktop?

Comment: @Ryan I pulled this screenshot off the blog link, although I checked each of the settings (which were also not configured).  I am logging into the server interactively through VPN and remote desktop.

Comment: When you log on after leaving your session logged in overnight, do you return to your desktop as it was the night before? Or does it create a brand new session for you? Maybe you're not actually being logged off, your app is just crashing? I've used ArcGIS before, and it was the buggiest most annoying PoS I've ever encountered, so I'm keen to blame it for anything.

Comment: @Ryan It appears as if a new session is started because the Server Manager window appears.  Yes, ArcGIS has been known to be bloatware although the stability in recent years has improved.